# jqgrid - copy row(s) with data from database

Tags: jqgrid, copy, row

I'm trying to copy a row, but I'm using the data from a database, and I'm returning it with JSON. I'd like to know if it's possible to make a copy of a row, and if can I delimited the number of times that I can copy the rows. For example, I need to copy a row with id = 6, but I need to make 5 copies of this row. How can I do that?

Comment: for what javascript or asp.net or something else?

Comment: @vishalsharma for javascript and I have some files with php too.

Comment: Do you want to copy rows on client's side first and after that send data to server. Or you want to copy rows on server side and after that reload grid?

Comment: use getRowData To Grab a Single row from jqgrid and then create an array by var s = new Array() and push the single row no of times you want .. send it to the server or tweak any way u want... is that ur answer?

Comment: @vishalsharma yes... but how can I send this to the server? And where do I have to do this getRowData, inside of a specific function or not!?

Comment: create a new column inside jqgrid .. using formatter place a link inside that column write handler for click over that link .. on that handler use getrowdata and grab the fields and then make a ajax call to send to the server...

Comment: @gv0zd I need to copy the row(s), and show to user that the rows were copied and added in the grid (so I don't know... I'm newbie, but I think I have to do this in client side first and then send to server, or am I wrong!?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make main work on server side not on client

In jqgrid decraration something like this:

```
grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    loadComplete: function(data) {
        var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');

        for (var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
            var id=ids[i];
            var rowData = thisGrid.jqGrid('getRowData', id);

            grid.jqGrid('setCell', id, 'buttons', '<input type="button" class="copy" value="Copy">');
        }

        $('button.copy').click(function (e) {
            var id = $(e.target).parents('tr')[0].id;

            $.ajax({
                url: 'some_url',
                dataType : "json",
                data: {'id': id},
                timeout: 10000,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
                },
            });
        });
    }
    ....
});
```

In php part  something like this

```
$array = array(
    'success'=>false
);

if(isset($_POST['id])) {
    if($db -> num_rows($q = $db->query("SELECT FROM ... WHERE `id` = ".intval($_POST['id'])) == 1) {
        $row = $db -> fetch_assoc($q);

        $db->query("INSERT INTO .....);
        $array['success'] = true;
    }
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

If you want to copy more than one time you could add some dialog on client side to input number of copies

Answer (score 0):

use getRowData To Grab a Single row from jqgrid and then create an array by var s = new Array() and push the single row no of times you want ..

create a new column inside jqgrid .. using formatter [Formatter In jQgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#t65) place a link inside that column write handler for click over that link .. on that handler use getrowdata and grab the fields and then make a ajax call to send to the server...

Comment: I have a custom button to copy the rows... Can I do these things inside the `onClickButton`? Or do I really need to create this new column?

Comment: no u can do that with yr custom button 's onclick. i have given that column idea for single row copy.. if you want multiple row than u can do that with custom button. no pro at all..